# nse india screen scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to Screen Scrape the Website - http://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=allAnnouncements. It has a lot of side bars and main screen which can be parameterized and scraped.

However when i see the source of the webpage, I can find no urls, no buttons no stuff that can be used via selenium and information browsed. I have scraped a lot of websites before with Selenium and BS4 but this is the first time that i am trying for this page.

Is there a way that we can use selenium for such websites. Any directions help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Depending where you are rightclicking the view the source will show different data. Can I suggest you use a web dev tool like FireBug(Firefox)?

Comment: On further debugging and looking at all the JS on the http://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html?id=allAnnouncements Page, the website uses JSON storage. Any idea how to scrape it?

Comment: @TidusJar - Let me check that out. I am using Chrome for now.

Comment: just press F12 then and use the Elements expector

Comment: Got it. The webpage uses layers and layers of JS. I finally reached to a http://www.nseindia.com/corporates/js/corpInfo/financialresults.js which hopefully loads the JSON that has the links. Is there a way that we can automate this via selenium

Comment: On selecting a Stock, it shows the results which is once again a pop up link :-( which is shown with the JSON call.. I have to identify the function and the inputs sent to the call to then automate it... Seems..the site has been deliberately made to avoid scraping.

Comment: @myloginid I'm not able to fetch the table containing the list of NIFTY50 listed companies data from [NSE Index List](http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm?cat=N) , url -> http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm?cat=N